# Haskell readLn no parse error

Tags: parsing, haskell, io

This function allows the user to input a list of strings. The function takes the length and allows the user to input length-1 more lines. Then each line is checked to ensure it is the same length as the original line. The code:

```
readme :: IO [Line]
readme = do
 line <- readLn
 let count = length line
 lines <- replicateM (count-1) $ do 
  line <- readLn
  if length line /= count 
  then fail "too long or too short"
  else return line 
 return $ line : lines
```

Line is of type String.

When I try to run the function and input.. say ["12","13"] I get the following: *** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse) and I can't figure out why, any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are trying to read something with the wrong type.

You say that `Line` is a `String` aka. `[Char]`. However, the input you are typing is of the format `["12", "13"]` which looks like it should have type `[Line]`, aka. `[String]` or `[[Char]]`.

You need to explain what a `Line` is *actually* supposed to be. If you want a `Line` to be a string, then why are you entering lists of strings at the terminal? Something is wrong with your logic in this case.

If you want a method for inputting square matrices, you can let `type Line = [Int]` instead, and use one of these formats:

```
-- What you type at the terminal:
1 -2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8

-- How to read it in your program:
line <- (map read . words) `fmap` getLine

-- What you type at the terminal:
[1, -2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[6, 7, 8]

-- How to read it in your program:
line <- readLn
```

If you really want to input lines, so that `type Line = [Char]`, and that each number in the input list becomes a unicode character, meaning that when you enter `[97, 98, 99]` on the terminal, you get the string `"abc"`:

```
-- What you type at the terminal:
[97, 98, 99]
[100, 101, 102]
[103, 104, 105]

-- How to read it in your program:
line <- (map toEnum) `fmap` readLn
```

Comment: Essentially readme is used to check the input of a Sudoku square to ensure the lines are of the same length, i.e. entering ["1","2","3"] means that 2 more lines should be input (as it will be a 3x3 grid) and both of which should be of length 3.

Answer (score 6):

If it's any help, your program accepts the following input:

```
*Main> readme
"abc"
"123"
"456"
["abc","123","456"]
```

You might have intended to write `getLine` instead of `readLn`, but without knowing the purpose of your program this is a bit hard to tell.

Changing to `getLine`, the program accepts:

```
*Main> readme
abc
123
456
["abc","123","456"]
```

Comment: He has a few older questions that explain his intents. He tried using `getLine` before, but apparently this was not what he wanted, because he wants to measure the lengths of the (logical) lists that the user inputs, and not the lengths of the strings.

Answer (score 4):

`read` is not very user friendly and it doesn't see `["12","13"]` as a string. It will accept `"123"` or `['1','2','3']` or even `"[\"12\",\"13\"]"` - in other words, the string has to be written as it would be in your program. In this case you don't need to use `read` because you're just reading a `String` so replacing `readLn` with `getLine` would work.

Comment: He does not actually want to read the input as strings; see the user's old questions for reference.

Comment: Wow, you really did your homework, have an upvote. Aside - did you write the ray tracer in your profile pic?

Comment: Very much off-topic, but the ray-tracer I used is [LuxRender](http://www.luxrender.net).